# Internet Connection Sharing with 2 Wifi NICs? one to receive other to transmit?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

In Windows 8, how do I make one Wifi NIC connect to the AP and the dongle Wifi NIC the Access Point?

I understand that I need to setup a "Wireless Hosted Network", but my question is, how do I bind my Wireless Hosted network to a specific Wifi adapter?

I want my high gain Wifi USB adapter used as the hotspot connection for the house and my internal wifi adapter used as the source of the connection.
Is this possible?

Simply bridging the connections doesn't create the wifi hotspot.  Using the available resources online only creates a virtual adapter.

Comment: You might find this article on setting up a hosted network in Windows 8 of use http://dottech.org/90970/windows-8-how-to-tether-internet-connection/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the *hosted network* builtin feature of Windows 7 and later:

It's quite simple to use, just issue the next command to create the network:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<YourAPName> key=<Password>
```

The you start it with this:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

And stop it with this:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
```

You can change the WPA password whenever you want with this:

```
netsh wlan refresh hostednetwork <NewPassword>
```

I'm unsure about which physical NIC it will use to share the network since it creates a virtual adapter on top of a physical, existent one; most commonly your first physical adapter (usually named as *Network Connection*, without any numbers, on the Control Panel's *Network Adapters* page).

Then you may just allow only your NIC (with mac filtering) to connect to your Access Point so no other machine connects to it except you, while the others connect to your machine.

Comment: thanks for this.. i updated my question to specifically ask how to bind this to a specific physical adapter .. since the one i want to use is high gain, unlike the internal nic. there must be a way of doing this.